# Счетчик времени (Java)

Tags: java

Есть сервер, на нем некоторый класс, при создании объекта которого начинается отсчет времени. Отсчет идет до тех пор пока существует объект. В любой момент времени клиент может запросить - сколько времени прошло с начала создания экземпляра. И таких экземпляров тысячи. Каждый отсчитывает время от начала своего создания.

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать так, чтобы при падении сервера отсчет времени во всех объектах не прекращался.

**Возможное решение:** я так понимаю надо в момент создания объекта сохранять это время куда-то на диск, а не во временной памяти, чтобы после падения сервера можно было восстановить время  момента первого создания объекта.

**Upd:**
И, возможно, для экономии оперативки при работе с большим количеством объектов, их лучше всегда сразу сохранять в БД и уничтожать, а потом вынимать и создавать новый эквивалентный объект, когда он будет необходим?

Comment: Пока верно рассуждаете. Если данные должны переживать перезапуск приложения, сохраняйте их на диск или в БД.

Comment: как сказали выше только на диск или в бд. иначе никак. Сам так делаю.